# Reference Voltage Tracking for DC-DC boost converter

Tags: power-electronics, control, boost, matlab, simulink

I have a boost converter which works perfectly with an s-domain controller (using a type-3 compensator and dual loop). Now, I need to do this using digital control (z-domain). I have converted the s-domain tf to z -domain using c2d with tustin/prewarp.

The Bode plots match for s and z. But controller does not track the 48V reference. Instead it just reaches 38V as shown in graph.

I do not recognize why the controller does not track the 48V reference. Does it has to do something with c2d command or the blocks are wrong in simulink?

**Boost Specs:**

- Vin = 30 V
- Vout = 48 V
- L = 10 mH
- C = 220 μF
- R = 10
- fs = 10 kHz

**Gvi = s1 , Gid = s2**

s1=(0.03372*s^2+168.8*s+1.35e5)/(s^3+1045*s^2+45000*s);

s2=(9.151e5*s^2+9.152e10*s+9.151e10)/(s^3+1.015e6*s^2+9.151e10*s);

z1=c2d(s1,0.001,'prewarp',2*pi*100)

z2=c2d(s2,0.001,'prewarp',2*pi*100)

The repeating sequence frequency is 10 kHz. The square wave generator frequency is also 10 kHz.

[image: Circuit]

[image: Output Voltage]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I tried some changes in the statement and highlighted the problem.

Comment: @Boost_Guy What is your question?

Comment: My question is what am I doing wrong that in z domain the boost converter does not track the 48V reference.

Comment: It's nearly working actually.

Comment: Yes it is. But still not working as good as it was working in s domain. In s domain it was actually tracking 48V. But in z domain it does not track 48V. I tried different z transfer functions with different sampling time and critical frequency but it does not work.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Simulink these days but does it track below 38V? If it does, then something may be saturating

Comment: If I use 40V as reference then it will track till 33V. If I use less than 40V reference then tracking fully fails and Vout=Vin=30V.